# Soup.find() returning None *only* on second iteration

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrape using BeautifulSoup in Python, and the first iteration of the code runs fine: values are assigned to article_name and article_name_new. However, on the second iteration soup.find() returns None, and so when I print(article_name_new) I get None, even though the exact same code is being carried out. Can anybody point out my likely very obvious mistake?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getNews():
    global my_nintendo_news_updated
    global article_name
    global quote_page
    global page
    global soup

    print(article_name)

    if my_nintendo_news_updated == False:
        article_name_new = soup.find( href=re.compile('https://mynintendonews.com/2018/'))
        print(article_name_new)
        if article_name_new != article_name:
            print('My Nintendo News has been updated')
            my_nintendo_news_updated = True
            print(article_name)
            print(article_name_new)
            B.configure(image = my_nintendo_news_icon)
            article_name = article_name_new
        else:
            print('My Nintendo News has not been updated')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    top.after(5000, getNews)
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but don't you think the last 2 lines should be inside the `if` or `else` block? Otherwise it will go into an infinite loop when the `my_nintendo_news_updated = True` gets executed.

Comment: Also, you're not sending any `request` in the `getNews` function. Are you sure you are updating the page response?

Comment: I'm eventually going to expand the code. As it stands, yes, but in the future I'll only cancel the loop when I've detected that multiple different sites have updated.

Comment: For your second question: I thought soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') would update the page response?

Comment: It doesn't send any request to the page, but simply create a BeautifulSoup object from the response you've stored in the `page` variable. You need to call `page = requests...` or whichever lib you are using everytime along with `soup` update or you won't get the updated data from the website.

Comment: Thank you very much; that's what I was fundamentally misunderstanding. I've put in page = urlopen(quote_page) above the BeautifulSoup line and it seems to be working.